# I need to test a controller method with Junit4, but unable to successfully do so. the method takes List<String> as parameter

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mocking

My controller method looks like this:
I am mocking the serviceImpls and controller

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@InjectMocks
private ModelController modelController;

@Mock
ModelServiceImpl modelServiceImpl;
.
.
.
    
    
    
@GetMapping(value = "/getDetails/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getDetails(@RequestParam(name="modelNames") List<String> modelNames) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(modelServiceImpl.getDetailsByModels(modelNames), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Test Method Looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testGetModelDetails() throws Exception {
    List<String> modelNames = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add("rishima");
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    results.add("star23563");

    when(modelServiceImpl.getDetailsByModels(modelNames)).thenReturn(results);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/getDetails/")).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());


}
```

But getting the error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
```

I have looked over the stackoverflow and tried but couldnt find solution for passing List as RequestParam.

Answer (score 1):

You should not accept `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` because `@RequestParam` are params for your URL, but regardless of that you can use `mockMvc.perform(get("/getDetails/").param("modelNames", "1,2,3")`